# What is the Max value for speed limit param in CloudLinux (lve)?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, cloudlinux

I can see in cloudLinux document that in cpu usage limit section, 150% means 1.5 cores : https://docs.cloudlinux.com/limits/#speed-limit

**My question is : for a server with 12 cores, if I want to use all cores, the correct value should be 1200% !?**

Why the recommended value for a High-end hosting introduced 200%?

Comment: What is "high-end hosting"? Introduced where?

Comment: @EsaJokinen In the mentioned URL (top of the page) you can find it.